Why is >= cheaper than > in Solidity?
Why are <= and >= cheaper than < and > in Solidity? In other words, how does Solidity implement them in Yul/assembly in a way that this happens? It does not seem intuitive to me at all. Because in yul, we have ‘lt’ and ‘gt’ opcodes but no equivalent for <= and >=.
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/
Can you tell me how exactly ">=", "<=", ">", and "<" in high-level Solidity are transformed to EVM language?
I tried remix simulation and could not find the answer.
PS: See line 164 of https://github.com/Uniswap/v4-core/blob/18b223cab19dc778d9d287a82d29fee3e99162b0/src/libraries/Pool.sol

You can find answer in this ethereum.stackexchange.com answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/151633/which-of-and-comparison-operators-use-less-gas-in-solidity
